# Better way for DB exception handling in java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Which one will be better: ErrorCode or Exception for that situation?

I have ever been seeing these two error handling techniques. I don't know the disadvantages and advantages for each technique.

```
public void doOperation(Data data) throws MyException {
    try {
        // do DB operation
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        /* It can be ChildRecordFoundException, ParentRecordNotFoundException
         * NullValueFoundException, DuplicateException, etc..
         */
        throw translateException(e);
    }
}
```

or

```
public void doOperation(Data data) throws MyException {
    try {
        // do DB operation
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        /* It can be "CHILD_RECORD_FOUND, "PARENT_RECORD_NOT_FOUND"
         * "NULL_VALUE_FOUND", "DUPLICATE_VALUE_FOUND", etc..
         */
        String errorCode = getErrorCode(e);
        MyException exc = new MyException();
        exc.setErrorCode(errorCode);
        throw exc;
    }
}
```

For second method, the error code retrieve form configuration file. We can add `Error Code` based on the `SQL Vender Code`.

SQL_ERROR_CODE.properties

```
#MySQL Database
1062=DUPLICATE_KEY_FOUND
1216=CHILD_RECORD_FOUND
1217=PARENT_RECORD_NOT_FOUND
1048=NULL_VALUE_FOUND
1205=RECORD_HAS_BEEN_LOCKED
```

Caller client for method 1

```
    try {

    } catch(MyException e) {
        if(e instanceof ChildRecordFoundException) {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e instanceof ParentRecordNotFoundException) {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e instanceof NullValueFoundException) {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e instanceof DuplicateException) {
            showMessage(...);
        }
    }
```

Caller client for method 2

```
    try {

    } catch(MyException e) {
        if(e.getErrorCode().equals("CHILD_RECORD_FOUND")) {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e.getErrorCode().equals("PARENT_RECORD_NOT_FOUND") {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e.getErrorCode().equals("NULL_VALUE_FOUND") {
            showMessage(...);
        } else if(e.getErrorCode().equals("DUPLICATE_VALUE_FOUND") {
            showMessage(...);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange question, since both approaches do the same thing: they transform a checked SqlException in a different exception which seems to be unchecked. So the first one is the better one because it moves this into a single method.

Both leave some questions to be asked:

- Isn't there some infrastructure that can do this conversion (Spring Template was mentioned in another answer)
- Do you really want checked Exceptions, in my mind they are hardly ever worth the trouble.
- Who is doing the real handling of the exception, does it get all the information needed? I would normaly expect some additional information about the transaction that failed inside of MyException, like: What did we try to do? (e.g. update a busines object); On what kind of object? (e.g. a Person); How can we/the user Identify the object (e.g. person.id + person.lastname + person.firstname). You will need this kind of information if you want to produce log/error message that tell you or your user more than 'Oops, something is wrong'
- Why is MyException mutable (at least in the 2nd example)

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using Spring's `JDBCTemplate`. It will translate most existing databases' exceptions into unchecked exceptions that are specific, e.g. `DataIntegrityViolationException`. It will also include the original SQL error in the message.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, it depends as how tightly your code is coupled with SQL.

If the method is to **always** (*1) be coupled with SQL, I would just declare and rethrow the `SQLException` (after cleanup / closing resources). Upper methods that are SQL-aware would then process it as they see fit (perhaps they need all the detail, perhaps they not).

If sometime in the future you could change the method for another which does not use SQL, then I would go for the second option.

(1): Be extra pessimistic with this assumption: "I think we are not going to change" should be interpreted as "Probably we will want to change". "We are not going to change" means "We cannot change without breaking lots of other methods anyway".

Answer (score 1):

A better design than either one would be to make your custom exceptions unchecked by extending `RuntimeException`.

I'd want your exception to wrap the first one, so coding it this way would be better, too:

```
MyException exception = new MyException(e); // wrap it.
```

If you do that, the second one is preferred.  More information is better.

Comment: Why would be a `RuntimeException` better? Any developer that uses this code will find about the exception when it happens (which could be at production time).

Comment: C# has shifted the idiom from unchecked to checked exceptions.  Spring framework does exactly what you're doing, except much better and 12 years ago.  They use unchecked exceptions.

Comment: why do you think, the second approach retains more information? All the information is comming from the exception which gets passed as an argument in the first example.

Comment: I know that SQLException in Java is a checked exception that explicitly retains vendor SQL error codes - something that no other checked exception does.  I'm assuming that the second one is in that spirit.

Answer (score 0):

One differnce would the way you will `catch` the exception. In the first cases you can just `catch` the exception and you know what the error is. In the second case you have to `catch` the exception and check the code to see what the error is.